# SVN externals missing after svnsync to another server

Tags: svn, svnsync

I have synced an SVN repository to a new server. I did this with the following command:

```
/bin/svnsync --non-interactive --username user --password password --trust-server-cert init file:///directory  https://svn-url
```

Then I also use the svnsync sync command to sync new SVN repo. Everything seemed fine so far.

However, when I accessed it, I noticed that the externally integrated repos were not integrated. So the externals are missing. What have I missed or done wrong?

Both repos (source and target) have the same version 1.10.2

Comment: Externals are in fact SVN properties (`svn:externals`). Are the properties gone for good, or just non functional?

Comment: They seem to have gone.

Comment: I would consider filing an issue including the command, the output of `svn proplist` of source and target and minimal reproduction instructions.